# Get primary keys inserted after executemany

Tags: python, mysql

I am using MySQLdb in python 3 to insert multiple rows using `executemany`.

Now I need to get the primary keys after the multi insert..

Is there any way to get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `connection.insert_id()`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `executemany` you insert multiple rows at a time. You will get first inserted rows primery key using `connection.inster_id()`

To get all inserted ids, you have to run another query.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-insert-id.html) you'll get the **first** auto-incremented value.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote last :). Only one we get is sure :)